# Create route on servce fabric

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

I created in visual studio service fabric with asp core.
After deploy I see hello world.
I created controller:

```
public class HomeController
{
    [HttpGet("~api/home")]
    public string Get()
    {
        return $"Hello from Service Fabric!. Log date: {DateTime.Now}";
    }
}
```

And change functional, where was Hello world:

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        /*app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
        });*/

        app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

But I still see Hello World. Do you have some idea, how it's fix?

Comment: The question is very vague. You need to describe an exact problem with concrete simple example. I doubt that is has anything to do with hosting on ASF - most likely a trivial ASP NET configuration issue.

Comment: Have you redeployed the application to the cluster?